# How do I manually proxy application/octet-stream (live video) in Go?

Tags: go, caching, proxy, video-streaming, streaming

I am trying to build an application which would act as a streaming proxy server with caching features. The thing is, I want to do it manually without using `NewSingleHostReverseProxy`. Manually means performing these steps:

1. Perform single `GET` request to the server
2. Read `resp.Body` to buffer and write to connected client(s)

And the issue is that VLC doesn't play anything. If I access stream directly - VLC plays it without problems, but if I do it via GO - VLC (as well as Kodi) just keeps buffering and never starts playing.

Things I've tried, but did not work:

1. `io.Copy(...)`
2. `bufio` reader/scanner and writing to the connected client. Flushing also did not help.

This is what `curl -v <stream_url>` says (accessing streaming url directly):

```
...
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
< Server: Myserver
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Connection: close
< 
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failed writing body (0 != 2896)
* Closing connection 0
```

This is what `curl -v <my_app_url>` says:

```
...
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Pragma: no-cache
< Server: Myserver
< Date: Sun, 29 Dec 2019 09:13:44 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failed writing body (0 != 14480)
* Failed reading the chunked-encoded stream
* Closing connection 0
```

---

Seems the issue is here, but how do I solve it?

Good:

```
* Failed writing body (0 != 2896)
* Closing connection 0
```

Bad:

```
* Failed writing body (0 != 14480)
* Failed reading the chunked-encoded stream
* Closing connection 0
```

---

Also adding a source code for example:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/stream", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/stream/videostream")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        reader := bufio.NewReader(resp.Body)
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        for {
            k, _ := reader.Read(buf)
            if k == 0 {
                break
            }
            w.Write(buf)
        }
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the server code.

Comment: Added source code

Comment: The copy loop does not handle the case where k != len(buf).   Fix the code by using io.Copy to copy the response.   The application does not propagate request and response headers between the client and the backend server.  That may or may not be a problem.

Comment: I already tried `io.Copy(...)`, tried `resp.Write(...)`, tried hijacking sessions and writing raw TCP as well as `httputil.NewChunked...` - data is being buffered, but never starts playing (as described in the post). Stream type is actually `mpeg-ts` and I think I should be looking into other go projects working with mpeg-ts streams.

Comment: The current copy code is broken and the easiest and best fix is to replace it with io.Copy.  Dump the request and response headers for the two cases and compare.

Answer (score 0):

I was building a dynamic *M3U* playlist and putting `.m3u8` ending on each link. All the links are of unknown type, so I thought media players will just look at *Content-Type* and handle media accordingly, but actually they look at URL endings as well (whether URL contains `.m3u8` or not).

If you put at the end of the link `.m3u8`, then set that link's Content-Type as `application/octet-stream` and provide actual `application/octet-stream` stream - players will never start showing any video stream. Solution - do not append `.m3u8` to URL if that URL is not `m3u8` format media. Without `m3u8` media players can still show the video.